# How enable and disable button in DevExpress

Tags: button, devexpress

I develop an application with DevExpress, but I have a problem in my code, I want a condition for my button "save", if condition "A" button save enable, but if condition "B" button save disable,but in my code the button "save" enable in the 2 cases.
 how to fix this problem?

```
 <%   if (Condition == A )
                                                      {
                                                 %>
                <td>

                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="BtSavelisteningScale" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="NotSet" 
                            ImagePosition="Left" Text="Enregistrer" VerticalAlign="NotSet" ClientEnabled="true" ClientInstanceName="BtSavelisteningScale"
                            Wrap="Default" AutoPostBack="false" meta:resourcekey="BtSavelisteningScaleResource1">
                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e){if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('grpVal')) {CPlEvalScale.PerformCallback('Enregistrer');} }" />
                            <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e){ if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('grpVal')) {GetScore();GvLs.PerformCallback('UpdateListenningScale');}}" />--%>
                        </dx:ASPxButton>

                  </td>

                    <% } %>
                    <%   else if (Condition == B )
                                                      {

                                                 %>

                 <td>
                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="BtSavelisteningScaleFalse" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="NotSet"

                            ImagePosition="Left" Text="Enregistrer" VerticalAlign="NotSet" ClientEnabled="false" ClientInstanceName="BtSavelisteningScale"
                            Wrap="Default" AutoPostBack="false" meta:resourcekey="BtSavelisteningScaleResource1">
                            <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e){if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('grpVal')) {CPlEvalScale.PerformCallback('Enregistrer');} }" />
                            <%--<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e){ if (ASPxClientEdit.ValidateGroup('grpVal')) {GetScore();GvLs.PerformCallback('UpdateListenningScale');}}" />--%>
                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                  </td>
                    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default Set it `Visiable = False` Then
`Page_Load` Event or `Page_Init` Event Check your condition. example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Condition == A)
        {
            BtSavelisteningScale.Visiable = True;
            BtSavelisteningScaleFalse.Visiable = False;
        }
        else if (Condition == B)
        {
            BtSavelisteningScale.Visiable = False;
            BtSavelisteningScaleFalse.Visiable = True;
        }
    }

Protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Condition == A)
            {
                BtSavelisteningScale.Visiable = True;
                BtSavelisteningScaleFalse.Visiable = False;
            }
            else if (Condition == B)
            {
                BtSavelisteningScale.Visiable = False;
                BtSavelisteningScaleFalse.Visiable = True;
            }
        }
```